# Dismissing 2 or more ViewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

Is it possible to dismiss 2 viewControllers efficiently?

I currently have 3 (or more) viewControllers.

View1 > presents View2 , View2 > presents View3, etc.. then when an action is triggered in View3 (or 4,5..), I need to return to the View1.

How is this done without creating a new View1 object?

Can i dissmis for example view2 in the same time when presenting view3?

Comment: Hows your view hierarchy looks like ? It's difficult to answer without knowing how you've setup your views.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - dismiss multiple ViewControllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944191/iphone-dismiss-multiple-viewcontrollers)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `popViewControllerAnimated: NO` and `popToRootViewController`.

You can also do smth. like that:

```
UINavigationController* navController = ...;
[navController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];
[navController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];
[navController pushViewController: anotherViewController];
```

Comment: because view1 is tabbar, and view2 is subview of tabbar. it is hard to explain, but i cant use UINavController here

Comment: then please tell us your code structure based on what classes are used in your view structure... or show some code. otherwise nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using navigation controller..

then you can just use

```
[ self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

other wise.. you can use delegate in each view and 
call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

in each view except in view 1 where you should call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

i creating view2 like UINavController. And then in every controller i can implement `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`.

Thnks every body for help