# How to dismiss all the modal views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Assuming I present a modal view B based on A, and then present a modal view C based on B.

Is there any way to dismiss both B and C and go back to A directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you use storyboards in XCode4.5, you can use the new unwind segue. Implement

```
 -(IBAction)back:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue
```

in A. (You can leave the function definition empty.) Then in the controller of C right click on the new exit icon and connect the new entry to the control that shall initiate the unwinding.

Comment: Unwind segues explained in four lines. Super helpful answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

yes, i have some solution,
probably it is a little bit dirty
but you can work around

```
UIViewController* vc = self;

while (vc) {
    UIViewController* temp = vc.presentingViewController;
    if (!temp.presentedViewController) {
        [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
        break;
    }
    vc =  temp;
}
```

you can call this from any of model controllers in your stack, all of them will be dismissed. We are just searching for the second one and then dismiss it.

Comment: can you illustrate it , i can't figure out how you get the temp (the one that presented vc ) , then , only if temp doesn't have presented views dismiss it , but when will it not has presented views

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call [B dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

this will dismiss B. of course, if C is presented from B, it will be dismissed too.

And, here is relative question, it contains complete answer.
[iPhone - dismiss multiple ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944191/iphone-dismiss-multiple-viewcontrollers)

Answer (score 0):

if there're *2* `ViewContronllers`, then:

`[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

if there are *3* ViewControllers, then :

`self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.presentViewController`