# How to dismiss all presented view controllers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, dismiss, presentviewcontroller

I want to change the `rootViewController` of the `keyWindow`, to do that I need to dismiss all presented view controllers (or a whole stack of presented view controllers).

I currently use this in AppDelegate,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
     UIWindow *window = self.window;
     window.rootViewController = [self makeAnotherVCAsRoot];
}];
```

I wrote about [presentingViewController](http://www.fantageek.com/1502/understand-presentingviewcontroller/), so in this case, I'm just lucky as the old `rootViewController` is the `presentingViewController`, as no view controllers have defined `definesPresentationContext`

I personally think that we should find the presented view controller stack, and dismiss it, instead of using rootViewController

Comment: If you want to dismiss all presented view controllers, you would generally use an unwind segue. See [Technical Note TN2298](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html).

Comment: @Rob How to do that in code, as I'm not using storyboard

Comment: If i understand you. then this is what i am doing in my app to dismiss all the presented view controllers `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` and then 
        `[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

Comment: @onmyway133 Unwind segues are for storyboards only.

Comment: @Rob sorry, I mean that I don't want to use storyboard. How to do that in code only ?

Comment: try this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944191/iphone-dismiss-multiple-viewcontrollers